# My cloned website build on nextjs won't load up

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, httrack

I have cloned a website from httrack and it's build on nextjs and react, now when I open index.html it loaded the header & footer but I'd doesn't load the body area, please provide a solution to this. How to fix it. Thank you

I tried an online react compiler in which I placed that index.html code and there it loaded perfectly. But on localhost it doesn't load. I can follow the steps if there is a need to build a react app or next JS app on visual studio I can create that. Also the package.json and index.js is missing in the httrack cloned files.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).